# Was Jeremy Clarkson's P45 pitch broadcast within a Dragons' Den episode?

Tags: crossovers, top-gear

In season 19, episode 1 of *Top Gear*, Jeremy Clarkson pitched a small car, the P45, in front of the cast of *Dragons' Den*. This segment appeared in the *Top Gear* television show. Did the same segment also appear in an episode of the *Dragons' Den* television show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it did not. The Top Gear skit only appeared in Top Gear. The skit is codenamed TG1, and the airdate is the airdate of the Top Gear episode (27 January 2013). No other episode mentions Top Gear in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragons'_Den_(UK_TV_series)#Other_programmes). The official summary for all 2013 Dragon's Den episodes on the [BBC Two website](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b006vq92/broadcasts/2013/03), don't include any reference to Top Gear either.